# Computing average grades for students in a class

Tags: python, csv, statistics

I wrote up a simple averages calculator for student grades, based on [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/1kphtf/081313_challenge_136_easy_student_management/) daily programming challenge.

First, the script asks for the file name for the text file containing the student names and grades. It is formatted like so:

```
JON 19 14 15 15 16
JEREMY 15 11 10 15 16
JESSE 19 17 20 19 18
```

The user is then asked how many assignments there are.

While my solution works, it seems awfully verbose. Can you give me tips on "pythonic" ways to simplify the script?

**grade_avg_generator.py**

```
"""Simple student grade manager"""

from fileinput import input


def import_data(grades_file, assignments):
    """Split the data into key value pairs."""
    student_grades = dict()
    for line in input(grades_file):
        this_line = line.split()
        student_grades[this_line[0]] = [int(item) for item in this_line[1:assignments + 1]]
    return student_grades


def student_means(student_grades):
    """Generate the average grade for each student and append it."""
    for k, v in student_grades.iteritems():
        grades = v
        grades_mean = float(sum(item for item in grades)) / len(grades)
        v.append(grades_mean)
    student_grades_mean = student_grades
    return student_grades_mean


def class_mean(student_grades_mean):
    """Generate the class average."""
    class_grades = list()
    for k, v in student_grades_mean.iteritems():
        this_avg = v[-1]
        class_grades.append(this_avg)
    class_mean = float(sum(item for item in class_grades)) / len(class_grades)
    return class_mean


def main():
    grades_file = raw_input('File name: ')
    assignments = int(raw_input('How many assignments are there? '))

    student_data = import_data(grades_file, assignments)
    student_data_avg = student_means(student_data)
    class_avg = class_mean(student_data_avg)
    print 'class average: %0.2f' % class_avg
    for k, v in student_data_avg.iteritems():
        grades = v[:-1]
        grades = ' '.join(str(i) for i in grades)
        avg = str(v[-1])
        print 'name: %s | grades: %s | average: %s' % (k, grades, avg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For conciseness in Python, the key is to think in terms of applying functions using `map` and list comprehensions, rather than thinking procedurally.  In this problem, it is very important to define a [`mean()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716331) function.  Once you do that, the calculations themselves are one-liners.

The main objection I had to your code was that you mangled the data structure by appending each student's average at the end of his grades.  Don't do that — `student_means()` should just return a fresh `dict` instead.

I've taken out the non-essential prompt for the number of assignments; you can easily put it back.

```
""" Simple student grade manager"""

from fileinput import input

def mean(list):
    return sum(map(float, list)) / len(list) \
      if len(list) > 0 else float('nan')

def import_student_grades(grades_file):
    """
    Given a filename, reads data into a dict whose keys are student names
    and whose values are grades (as strings).
    """
    line_words = [line.split() for line in input(grades_file)]
    return dict((words[0], words[1:]) for words in line_words)

def main():
    grades_file = raw_input('File name: ')
    student_grades = import_student_grades(grades_file)
    student_means = dict((k, mean(v)) for k, v in student_grades.iteritems())

    print 'class average: %0.2f' % mean(student_means.values())
    for name, grades in student_grades.iteritems():
        print 'name: %(name)s | grades: %(grades)s | average: %(avg)0.2f' % {
            'name': name,
            'grades': ' '.join(grades),
            'avg': student_means[name],
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```